# Log into website using R, rvest session - not able to set unnamed fields

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

**Edit:** updated with real, working login credentials, and with a few efforts we've tried, to no success

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

login_to_website <- function() {
  # Login, create a web session with the desired login address
  login_url <- "https://www.sportsbettingdime.com/plus/register/"
  pgsession <- session(login_url); Sys.sleep(1)
  
  # grab & submit 1st form on page
  pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]];
  filled_form <- html_form_set(pgform, email="nickcanova@gmail.com", password="tpe.vxp3ZRT!twq.wkd"); # not working
  session_submit(pgsession, filled_form); Sys.sleep(1)
  
  # return session to use in other functions
  return(pgsession)
}
```

We are looking to log into this website, however the fields in the `pgform` that is returned (`pgform$fields`) are unnamed. They is no `name` field in the form when you inspect the website either...

```
> pgform
<form> '<unnamed>' (GET )
  <field> (text) : 
  <field> (password) : 
  <field> (button) : 
>
```

As a result, the `html_form_set` call doesn't work, throwing the error `Error: Can't set value of fields that don't exist: ' email ', ' password '`.

**EDIT:** It looks like this works for setting the fields (replace `html_form_set` with these 4 lines below), however the result still does not end us logged in...

```
pgform$fields[1][[1]]$value <- 'nickcanova@gmail.com' # add email
pgform$fields[2][[1]]$value <- 'tpe.vxp3ZRT!twq.wkd'  # add password
pgform$method = "POST"       # change from GET to POST
pgform$action <- login_url   # was NULL, cant be NULL, set to login_url? (not sure here)
```

We set the method to `POST` and we set the action to the `url` solely because, in another function that logs into a different website, the `method` is POST and the `action` is the URL of the page? Not sure if these are correct though...

**How to check if login is successful** - in the code below, the columns for `money` and `sharp` are omitted when not logged in, and available when logged in. Currently we are getting all NA values in these last 2 columns, the goal is to get actual numbers in these 2 fields:

```
page_url <- paste0('https://www.sportsbettingdime.com/', league, '/odds/')
page_overall <- pgsession %>% session_jump_to(page_url)
table_list <-  page_overall %>% html_nodes('table.odds-table') %>% html_table()

df1 <- table_list[1] %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(df1) = c('teams', 'spread1', 'spread2', 'spread3', 'spread4', 'spread5', 'bet', 'money', 'sharp', 'bet2')
df1[, c('money', 'sharp')]
```

Comment: That form seems to take inputs for Amazon Cognito authentication, i.e. it depends on javascript, password itself is not sent out, just the hash, and auth. data is not posted to sportsbettingdime.com but cognito-idp at amazonaws.com. Should probably switch to RSelenium.

Comment: We saw references to AWS Cognito in the network tab, but didn't know this is what it meant. We always prefer to avoid Selenium at all costs but understand not every website can be logged into without it.